# Ansible vars _prompt: playbook fails before value can be assigned to variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

As an example:

```yaml
- name: SET_STEP1
  prompt: "Set value for step 1"
  default: "the value for step 1"
  private: no

- name: SET_STEP2
  prompt: "Set value for step 2"
  default: "{{ SET_STEP2 }} depends on the value of {{ SET_STEP1 }}"
  private: no
```

Result: `ERROR! 'SET_STEP1' is undefined`

Even though a default value is assigned, this will not run, because Ansible thinks `SET_STEP1` is undefined. `SET_STEP2` can only be correctly defined after `SET_STEP1` is defined by the user, or the default value is assumed.

How can I achieve this?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Even though a default value is assigned, this will not run, because Ansible thinks `SET_STEP1` is undefined*

Unfortunately not. At the time Ansible is parsing through the `vars_prompt` section, the variable is undefined. Therefore such construct has to fail and produce an error.

> *`SET_STEP2` can only be correctly defined after `SET_STEP1` is defined by the user, or the default value is assumed. How can I achieve this?*

According [Interactive input: prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)

> *Prompts for individual `vars_prompt` variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line `--extra-vars` option,*

you could use an approach like

```bash
ansible-playbook vars_prompt.yml --extra-vars="username=TEST"
Provide password for TEST: _
```

or within the `tasks` section the [`pause` module with parameter `prompt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#examples)

```yaml
- name: Gather SET_STEP2
  ansible.builtin.pause:
    prompt: "Set value for step 2"
    echo: no
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: result

- name: SET_STEP2
  set_fact:
    SET_STEP: "{{ result.user_input }}"
```

or define variables.

**Further Documentation**

- [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime)
- [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)
- [Adding variables to inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory)
- [`include_vars` module – Load variables from files, dynamically within a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html)

---

Furthermore, and using the example from Ansible documentation, a test like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    username: "root"

  vars_prompt:

    - name: username
      prompt: "What is your username?"
      private: false

    - name: password
      prompt: "Provide password for {{ username }}"
      private: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show username and password
    debug:
      msg: "{{ username }}:{{ password }}"
```

will result into an output of

```bash
What is your username?: test
Provide password for root:

PLAY [localhost] ***********

TASK [Show username and password] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test:test
```

*... *see that the username defaults to root, interactive entered is test, printed is root and the value is set for test**

So, parts of your given example or requirement are technically not possible, at least not in that way.